# Micropython automatically converting carriage returns to newlines

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I was looking to modify some terminal code to make it portable and work nicely with windows clients and encountered this issue.

When I press enter in a windows terminal, MicroPython (v1.19.1 on a Raspberry Pi Pico) appears to recieve 2 linefeed characters (0x0A + 0x0A) instead of a carriage return then a linefeed (0x0D + 0x0A).

Code:

```python
import sys

while(True):
    b = sys.stdin.read(1)
    sys.stdout.write("(" + hex(ord(b)) + ")")
```

Run the code, connect to port using a [modified PuTTY](https://github.com/gniemirowski/putty-crlf) configured to send a CRLF, hit enter and you get:

[image]

I get similar results when using the Thonny Shell or the REPL shell included in the Micropython plugin for PyCharm.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a quirk (or bug) with MicroPython?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is standard behaviour for Python, so has been implemented in MicroPython.

It's related to [PEP 278 – Universal Newline Support](https://peps.python.org/pep-0278/), which translates all newlines to a single linefeed `"\n"`.

In this particular case, because I'm reading the characters one-by-one it has no chance to detect the CR + LF together and translate them to a single LF, so each is read, and the CR gets turned into an LF, and the LF makes it through unmodified.

You can use `sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)` to get the unmodified stream, in which case my test code becomes:

```python
import sys

while(True):
    b = sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)
    print("(" + hex(ord(b)) + ")")
```

This produces the expected output:

[image]